# How to program a connection pool?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, boost-asio

Is there a known algorithm for implementing a connection pool? If not what are the known algorithms and what are their trade-offs?
What design patterns are common when designing and programming a connection pool?
Are there any code examples implement a connection pool using boost.asio?
Is it a good idea to use a connection pool for persisting connections (not http)?
How is threading related to connection pooling? When do you need a new thread?

Comment: One question at a time is good practice here.

Comment: They are all related, would you prefer that I bombard stackoverflow with a question for each of these related questions?

Comment: I think the issue is that your question makes people think you haven't done any research about the topic and that you want all the answers (similar to 'homework' questions). Although not an invalid way of asking, it makes it, in my opinion, not easy for people to participate.

Comment: I have searched in google and read the wikipedia article. I would like to have links to resources as well if you've got any. I haven't found much of them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are looking for a pure thread-pooling policy (may be a connection or any resource) there are two simple approaches viz:-

1. Half Sync/Half Async Model (usually using using message queues to pass information).
2. Leaders/Followers Model (usually using request queues to pass information).

The first approach goes like this:-

- You create a pool of threads to
  handle a resource. Often this size
  (number of threads) needs to be
  configurable. Call these threads
  '**Workers**'.
- You then create a master thread that
  will dispatch the work to the
  **Worker** threads. The application program dispatches the *task* as a
  ***message*** to the master thread.
- The master thread puts the same on
  the message Q of a chosen **Worker**
  thread and the **Worker** thread removes itself from the
  pool. Choosing and removing the
  **Worker** thread needs synchronization.
- After the **Worker** completes the
  task, it returns to the thread-pool.

The master thread itself can consume the tasks it gets in *FCFS* or a *prioritized* manner. This will depend on your implementation.

The second model (Leader/Followers) goes something like this:-

- Create a thread pool. Initially all
  are **Workers**. Then elect a
  **Leader**, automatically rest-all become followers. Note that electing
  a **Leader** has to be synchronized.
- Put all the data to be processed on a
  single **request Q**.
- The thread-pool **Leader** dequeues
  the *task*. It then immediately
  elects a **new Leader** and starts executing the task.
- The new Leader picks up the next
  task.

There may be other approaches as well, but the ones outlined above are simple that work with most use-cases.

Half Sync/Half Async Major Weakness:-

- Higher context switching,
  synchronization, and data copying
  overhead.

Leader/Follwers Major Weakness:-

- Implementation *complexity* of
  **Leader** election in thread pool.

Now you can decide for yourself the *more correct* approach.
HTH,

Comment: This is really helpful. I thank you very much.
The second approach sounds interesting but how would one select a leader? Would it be the thread object that is available? What if there are no availabe threads in the pool? Should the current leader execute the task and wait for another thread to become available or should it keep his role as a leader?
Is the connection pool basically some collection of threads? Should it be a vector? A list? A set? In this approach how would I get the tasks need to be done (Sent by clients)? Is the leader responsible for that?

Comment: After recieving the name of those common patternes I googled and found this: http://www.kircher-schwanninger.de/michael/publications/lf.pdf
I will read it through and it looks interesting.

Comment: @the_drow: Leader is just another thread but which has to take the task. There always has to be a leader, if all threads in the pool are busy then the task has to wait in the request Q for the new leader to be elected. Once there is a leader it will take care of the task. Again this request Q may be FCFS or priority based. The link you found is indeed a decent one, you may consider the approaches given there.

Comment: @the_drow: see http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/PDF/lf-PLOPD.pdf on how ACE implements it.